# Deploy custom service on non hadoop node with Apache Ambari

Tags: hadoop, service, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I want to deploy a custom service onto non hadoop nodes using Apache Ambari.
I have created a custom service inside 
/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/common-services as opposed to Hadoop's folder of:
/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks/HDP

And then I restarted my ambari-server.
But with web, I cannot see my new Service.

Am I missing anything, do I have to register my custom service anywhere?

Hi, I don’t want to hardcode my service version into metainfo.xml, Can I do it?

```
<service>
  <name>DUMMY_APP</name>
  <displayName>My Dummy APP</displayName>
  <comment>This is a distributed app.</comment>
  <version>0.1</version> --------------This I don't want to hardcode, Can I doit?
  <components>
  ...
  </components>
</service>
```

Comment: I have 1 more question: How can I do hosts specific configuration using apache ambari? Can I do it or whatever configuration I have selected applies for all the hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need to specify in the stack definition that your service is available for that particular stack. Common Services is just a place to maintain a common set of service definitions which can be used as part of a stack definition through extension.

For Example, lets say you have created custom service 'MYSERVICE' with a version identifier of '1.0' and want it to be provided for the HDP 2.2 stack.

- You would need to place your service definition at the following location:

  ```
  /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/common-services/MYSERVICE/1.0
  ```

  This above directory would contain your metainfo.xml file and your configuration and package folder. This will be the base definition of your service.

  **Note**: It is also important to note that the version you specify in `/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/common-services/MYSERVICE/1.0/metainfo.xml` must match the version number you have indicated in the path. For our example that would be `<version>1.0</version>`.
- You will then also need to add an additional metainfo.xml file to the HDP 2.2 stack that will provide this service.

  ```
  /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks/HDP/2.2/services/MYSERVICE/metainfo.xml
  ```

  The contents of this file would be:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <metainfo>
    <schemaVersion>2.0</schemaVersion>
    <services>
      <service>
        <name>MYSERVICE</name>
        <extends>common-services/MYSERVICE/1.0</extends>
      </service>
    </services>
  </metainfo>
  ```

Comment: Thanks Cjackson!!!, but then I will not be able to install my service on bare machine without hadoop? So hadoop stack version is compulsary? I just want my service to be deployed on any OS machine

Comment: /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks/HDP is not 'Hadoops' folder. It's the Hortonworks Data Platform Stack. You could define your own stack and only list your custom service in that stack.

Comment: Ok one more query, How can I add my custom service to web ui without having to go through installation of new cluster and adding other services?

Comment: Hi, I don’t want to hardcode my service version into metainfo.xml, Can I do it?                                                                                                       <service>
    <name>DUMMY_APP</name>
    <displayName>My Dummy APP</displayName>
    <comment>This is a distributed app.</comment>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <components>
    ...
    </components>

Comment: Why don't you want to hardcode it? There has to be a value there. If you explain to me why you don't want to hardcode it and what you're trying to achieve I may be able to help further.

Comment: I don't want to hardcode the value because I want metainfo.xml version of custom service to be same as my actual product version. So when I change my product version, it should also be reflected for my custom service.

Comment: What build tools are you using?

Comment: maven to build my service

Comment: Ask a new question about how to dynamically create the version number within the metainfo.xml file using maven build processes and I'll be happy to answer it. These comments/discussion is off track from your original question.

Comment: Hi cjackson, I have created a new question if you could answer on that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431879/dynamically-create-the-version-number-within-the-ambaris-metainfo-xml-file-usin